# После обновления на Angular 5 приложение начало безбожно виснуть

Tags: angular5

Есть приложение использующее связку Angular + Clarity + Firebase (AngularFire 2). После обновления ангуляра до пятой версии так же пришлось обновить и AngularFire  до актуальной версии, немного поправить код под новую версию и вот вроде бы чудо - оно заработало. Работает увы недолго, через полминуты открывания-закрывания форм все начинает сначала лагать, а затем и наглухо виснет. Ошибок в консоли нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, где и как можно найти причины такого поведения! 
Заранее премного благодарен!

Comment: Вкладка Performance - профилируй. По описанию похоже на утечки памяти (возможно таймеров или подписок). Раз это ангуляр, могу предположить добавление подписок на Observable (не являющиеся http-запросами), от которых не делается отписок.

Comment: @Qwertiy я больше скажу, отписок в коде вообще нет) это проблема, да. Вот только почему на старых библиотеках все прекрасно и шустро работало, и в подписках ли проблемы. С профайлером тоже проблемы, он вместе с приложением виснет)

Comment: Ну так профилируй до того, как зависнет. Утечки подчистишь и виснуть перестанет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ: Кошмар...оказалось коллега в шаблоне вместо значения привязал метод с подписками (+ еще и в ngFor), в итоге шаблон бесперебойно дергал этот метод, создавалась орда подписок и память улетала очень быстро. Не делайте так никогда, уважаемые коллеги)